# Install Debezium SQL Server CDC Source Connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am following the link below to install the SQL Server CDC connector

https://www.confluent.io/hub/debezium/debezium-connector-sqlserver

But gets the error message

> Unable to detect Confluent Platform installation. Specify
> --component-dir and --worker-configs explicitly.
> Error: Invalid options or arguments

This is on my development machine I am trying to set up the connector.

**Kafka folder**
~/kafka

**Kafka plugin folder**
/usr/local/share/kafka/plugins

I also tried to install it manually by following the link https://docs.confluent.io/home/connect/install.html

but not sure about the plugin.path

**OS:** Ubuntu 20.04

Can you help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> not sure about the plugin.path

Using Confluent hub command sets that for you. As you've already said, it's `/usr/local/share/kafka/plugins`, so you give that as  `--component-dir` argument

Then you need to find your Kafka Connect property file and give it to `--worker-configs`